# PHP and MySQL: Saving multiple values using IMPLODE, reading and returning them using EXPLODE?

Tags: php, mysql, explode, implode

My file **optherapie.php** contains the following PHP and HTML code:

```
<?php
[...]
if ($_POST['cbOP2Revision'] == '2') {
  $optherapie->setOP2Revision($_POST['cbOP2Revision']);
  $OP2RevisionIndikation = implode(', ', $_POST['cbOP2RevisionIndikation']);
  $optherapie->setOP2RevisionIndikation($OP2RevisionIndikation);
  $OP2RevisionArt = implode(', ', $_POST['cbOP2RevisionArt']);
  $optherapie->setOP2RevisionArt($OP2RevisionArt);
  //$optherapie->setOP2RevisionIndikation($_POST['cbOP2RevisionIndikation']);
  //$optherapie->setOP2RevisionArt($_POST['cbOP2RevisionArt']);
}
[...]
?>

[...]

<div id="OP2_RevisionIndikationArt" style="display:none">

<table width="95%" align="center" border="<?= $BORDER_TABLE ?>" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" frame="" style="margin-left: 40px;" >
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 185px" />
<col />
</colgroup>

<tr>
  <td class="tablecontent" style="background-color: <?= $DATA_COLOR ?>;" >
    <?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionIndikation', 'Indication') ?>
  </td>
  <td class="tablecontent" style="background-color: <?= $DATA_COLOR ?>;">
    <select id="op2revindselect" name="cbOP2RevisionIndikation[]" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Mehrfachauswahl durch Ctrl/Strg + LMausClick ...">
    <!-- <option><?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionIndikationChoice', 'revision surgery - please choose') ?></option> !-->
    <option value="1" <?= $optherapie->getOP2RevisionIndikation() == '1' ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionIndikation1', 'Inner Hernia (Meso)') ?></option>
    <option value="2" <?= $optherapie->getOP2RevisionIndikation() == '2' ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionIndikation2', 'Inner Hernia (PETERSON)') ?></option>
    <option value="3" <?= $optherapie->getOP2RevisionIndikation() == '3' ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionIndikation3', 'Weight Regain') ?></option>
    <option value="4" <?= $optherapie->getOP2RevisionIndikation() == '4' ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionIndikation4', 'Weight Loss Failure') ?></option>
    [...]
    <option value="17" <?= $optherapie->getOP2RevisionIndikation() == '17' ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionIndikation17', 'Leakage') ?></option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="tablecontent" style="background-color: <?= $DATA_COLOR ?>;" >
    <?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionArt', 'Type') ?>
  </td>
  <td class="tablecontent" style="background-color: <?= $DATA_COLOR ?>;">
    <select id="op2revartselect" name="cbOP2RevisionArt[]" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Mehrfachauswahl durch Ctrl/Strg + LMausClick ...">
    <!-- <option><?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionArtChoice', 'revision surgery - please choose') ?></option> !-->
    <option value="1" <?= $optherapie->getOP2RevisionArt() == '1' ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionArt1', 'Devolvement laparoscopically') ?></option>
    <option value="2" <?= $optherapie->getOP2RevisionArt() == '2' ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionArt2', 'Devolvement openly') ?></option>
    <option value="3" <?= $optherapie->getOP2RevisionArt() == '3' ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionArt3', 'Dilatation') ?></option>
    <option value="4" <?= $optherapie->getOP2RevisionArt() == '4' ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionArt4', 'Band Explantation') ?></option>
    [...]
    <option value="20" <?= $optherapie->getOP2RevisionArt() == '20' ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?= $oLanguage->getExpression('optherapy', 'revisionArt20', 'Stent Implantation') ?></option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

</table>

</div>
```

This code does what it shall do: The choice of e. g. the first two options, respectively, are written into the database as "1, 2".

The object class for **reading** the database values looks like this in **PHP5_classOPTherapie.php**:

```
[...]
$qBaseline = 'SELECT ' .
             ' timestamp, ' .
             ' Datum, ' .
             ' DurchfuehrungVerantwortung, ' .
             ' OPTherapie, ' .
             [...]
             ' OP2RevisionIndikation, ' .
             ' OP2RevisionArt, ' .
             [...]
             ' FROM dat_optherapie ' .
             " WHERE patID = $this->iPatientID " .
             " AND revision = $rev; ";

$rResult = $oDatabase->query($qBaseline);

if ($oDatabase->getNumRows($rResult) == 0) {
  echo '<p class="error">Es sind keine noch Daten vorhanden!</p><br />';
} else {
  $aBaselineData = $oDatabase->getArrayAssoc($rResult);
[...]
//$haveOP2RevisionIndikation = explode(', ', $aBaselineData['OP2RevisionIndikation']);
//$this->setOP2RevisionIndikation($haveOP2RevisionIndikation);
//$haveOP2RevisionArt = explode(', ', $aBaselineData['OP2RevisionArt']);
//$this->setOP2RevisionArt($haveOP2RevisionArt);
$this->setOP2RevisionIndikation($aBaselineData['OP2RevisionIndikation']));
$this->setOP2RevisionArt($aBaselineData['OP2RevisionArt']);
```

The object class for **saving** the database values looks like this in **PHP5_classOPTherapie.php**:

```
[...]
$OP2RevisionIndikation = $this->getOP2RevisionIndikation();
$OP2RevisionArt = $this->getOP2RevisionArt();
[...]
$qInsertBase = 'INSERT INTO dat_optherapie (' .
               ' patID, ' .
               ' sessionID, ' .
               ' timestamp, ' .
               ' userID, ' .
               ' Datum, ' .
               ' DurchfuehrungVerantwortung, ' .
               ' revision, ' .
               ' OPTherapie, ' .
               [...]
               ' OP2RevisionIndikation, ' .
               ' OP2RevisionArt, ' .
               [...]
               'VALUES (' .
               " '$iPatientID', " .
               " '$sessionID', " .
               " now(), " .
               " '$iUserID', " .
               " '$Datum', " .
               " '$DurchfuehrungVerantwortung', ".
               " '$rev', " .
               " '$OPTherapie',  " .
               [...]
               " '$OP2RevisionIndikation', " .
               " '$OP2RevisionArt', " .
               [...]
```

Now, as stated, this does as much as save the values "1, 2" properly into the database.

Now my **questions**:

The reading methods enable the display of single database entries such as "3" into its original form "Weight Regain", but not of the "1, 2" - nothing is being displayed (, since I have not exploded them).

1. Where do I have to explode them so that the original user choices will be displayed again?
2. Could the implosion using ', ' instead of e. g. ' ' (i. e. without the comma, merely a blank) be the problem of reading and displaying the database entries?

Comment: I would prefer using json_encode, json_decoe. If there's any comma in your data, you will get errored data when exploding. Also there are other solutions, like serializing the data.

Comment: @Tanvir: Thank you, I have saved the data now without the comma in the database, just divided by a blank. But where shall I put the explosion in the code?

JSON codes are welcome and not the issue here. Here, I want to handle the implosion with an explosion.

Comment: If the query is Ok you should get the data at: $aBaselineData = $oDatabase->getArrayAssoc($rResult); Here please check if the data is Ok using print_r($aBaselineData); You shoould see the column data($aBaselineData['OP2RevisionArt']) on which you saved the imploded data as string. You can use explode on it: explode($aBaselineData['OP2RevisionArt']);

Comment: Also before the insertion what is going on at: $OP2RevisionArt = $this->getOP2RevisionArt(); Is it replacing the imploded data?

Comment: @Tanvir: The query is OK and does what it is meant to do: SAVE the data blank-separated as numbers into the database. The data are failproof existent in the database.

But exploding it like

    $this->setOP2RevisionIndikation(explode($aBaselineData['OP2RevisionIndikation']));

does not lead me anywhere, the data are still not displayed.

Comment: Are you getting the data Ok in the search query? Can you please print_r() on the seached data and share here?

Comment: @Tanvir:

[...]
 [OP2RevisionIndikation] => 1 2
[...]

Comment: Then please use: explode(' ',  $aBaselineData['OP2RevisionIndikation']); The single space(' ') is the delimiter.

Comment: `$this->setOP2RevisionIndikation(explode(' ', $aBaselineData['OP2RevisionIndikation']));
$this->setOP2RevisionArt(explode (' ', $aBaselineData['OP2RevisionArt']));`

No display result.

Comment: Does only: echo explode(' ', $aBaselineData['OP2RevisionIndikation']); echo explode (' ', $aBaselineData['OP2RevisionArt']); prints any result?

Comment: @Tanvir: echo not, but print_r:
`Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )`
I cannot see echo results from within the code, this has been eliminated.

Comment: @Tanvir: No results againn under
`explode(' ', $this->setOP2RevisionIndikation($aBaselineData['OP2RevisionIndikation']));
      explode(' ', $this->setOP2RevisionArt($aBaselineData['OP2RevisionArt']));`

Comment: You are getting the explode data ok. I think you need to  check the methods: setOP2RevisionIndikation() & setOP2RevisionArt().

Comment: @Tanvir: The definitions are as follows:
`public function setOP2RevisionIndikation($m) {
    $this->OP2RevisionIndikation = $m;
  }
  
  public function setOP2RevisionArt($m) {
    $this->OP2RevisionArt = $m;
  }`

Comment: @mtjmohr It looks like you have the information what the keys are available only in PHP, not in MySQL. So you might want to explode the value in PHP. But why do you save the selection as a comma separated list anyway? Why do you not use a separated table with the selection, which is known as [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)?

Comment: @Progman: Thank you for your reply. The values are stored accordingly in MySQL by numeric values, comma-separated up to now, blank-separated from now on, by implosion into one single field. And imploded fields should be re-explodable throughout the same mechanism. I am able to explode every value, but not within the object-oriented PHP complexity of a source code which I have to take care of now (it has not been my own development). Therefore, the task remains to tackle this explosion, but I do not see where to put it to so as to make the dtabase entries displayed again in the form.